# Combine results of multiple MySQL select queries

Tags: mysql, select

I am a MySQL novice, and looking for help on combining query results. I have three different SELECT queries that are used to select a list of users based on a date range of how long they have been members: between 10 and 25 years, between 25 and 50 years,  and 50 or more years. These queries are currently as follows:

To return members of at least 10 years but less than 25:

```
SELECT `user`.id AS "Member #",
`user`.initiation_date AS "Initiation Date"
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.initiation_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 YEAR
```

To return members of at least 25 years but less than 50:

```
SELECT `user`.id AS "Member #",
`user`.initiation_date AS "Initiation Date"
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.initiation_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
```

To return members of at least 50 years:

```
SELECT `user`.id AS "Member #",
`user`.initiation_date AS "Initiation Date"
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.initiation_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR
```

These three seem to work well independently, but my goal is to combine the results of these queries to return the user.id, user.initiation_date, as well as a third column that would identify if the member is in the "10 Year" (query 1), "25 Year" (query 2), or "50 Year" (query 3) range.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, this will work.

```
SELECT `user`.id AS Member_No,
    `user`.initiation_date AS Initiation_Date,
    (CASE WHEN `user`.initiation_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 YEAR) THEN '10 Year' 
          WHEN `user`.initiation_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR) THEN '25 Year'
          WHEN `user`.initiation_date <= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR) THEN '50 Year'
          ELSE 'None'
           END) AS Year_category
    FROM `user`
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Two options here.

Option 1 (UNION)

```
SELECT `user`.id AS "Member #",
`user`.initiation_date AS "Initiation Date",
"10 Year" AS myRange
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.initiation_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR

UNION

SELECT `user`.id AS "Member #",
`user`.initiation_date AS "Initiation Date",
"25 Year" AS myRange
FROM `user`
WHERE `user`.initiation_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR
```

etc.

Option 2 (CASE)

You can also use the WHERE clause to select those members who have had membership for 10 years or more, and then use a CASE clause within your SELECT statement.